# change IPython Notebook JSON file encoding

Tags: json, character-encoding, jupyter-notebook

By default, the JSON notebooks' encoding is ASCII:

```
{
 "cell_type": "heading",
 "level": 3,
 "metadata": {},
 "source": [
  "2.1.4. Nombre d'\u00e9l\u00e9ments: call/function/len"
 ]
},
```

Is it possible to change that into UTF-8?

```
{
 "cell_type": "heading",
 "level": 3,
 "metadata": {},
 "source": [
  "2.1.4. Nombre d'éléments: call/function/len"
 ]
},
```

I thought the option would be [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/config/options/notebook.html), but I cannot figure out which one would make the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>No it's not possible. You are mistaking the file encoding and the JSON encoding.
If you actually look at the file encoding you will see that it is UTF-8 (in vim)</del>:

```
    {
     "cells": [
      {
       "cell_type": "markdown",
       "metadata": {
        "internals": {
    encoding? encoding=utf-8
```

<del>There is no way to change json encoding, it does not make sens. The json parser you use shoudl convert automatically to/from whatever encoding you use in your programs.</del>

[update] On current developpement version of IPython (future 3.0) the function responsible to write the file on disk now try to write it as UTF-8, so this should be fixed. Cf [PR 7144](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/7144/files). There is no way to configure back to plain ASCII though.

Comment: OK, Matt, thanks for the reply. Since there is a parameter for that in the Python module json, i.e., ensure_ascii=False, I thought it was possible to use the same capability when creating the notebook.

Comment: As for the sense of my request: I have a bunch of .ipynb which I frequently multi-file-search with my text editor (fast and convenient). The encoding just prevents me to find accents, and so on.

Comment: I'll see what we can do, but if we do not use ASCII, we might be incompatible with other Json readers.

Comment: ... which is certainly more important a consideration than my (rather special) use case, I must confess :-)

Comment: Apparently that shouldn't change things for many json parser. I guess we'll give it a shot. It you want to send a PR....