# How to output chinese characters in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, jupyter-notebook

The column `['douban_info']` in my dataset is info about movies in Chinese which stored in JSON, so when I do `df['douban_info'][0]`, it returns:

[image]

The Chinese characters are all changed into things like `\u7834\u6653\u8005`, which I can't read with ease. Is it possible to make Python to turn them into the original Chinese when outputting?

I'm using Python 2.7 in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Using python 3 will fix this, as it changes `repr` to return unicode instead of `bytes`

Comment: @Eric is it possible that I can `import` anything in python 2 to fix this? (like I import division from future). Changing the python version is a big thing.

Comment: If you're using a lot of chinese script, you're going to have a much better time with 3 than 2.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots.  Cut-and-paste the actual text for your question.  Don't expect people to retype your example when trying to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how Python 2 works.  It by default displays the `repr()` when generating display strings for lists and strings.  You have to `print` strings to see the Unicode characters:

```
>>> D = {u'aka': [u'2019\u730e\u8840\u90fd\u5e02(\u6e2f)', u'\u9ece\u660e\u65f6\u5206']}
>>> D[u'aka'][0]
u'2019\u730e\u8840\u90fd\u5e02(\u6e2f)'
>>> print D[u'aka'][0]
2019猎血都市(港)
```

If you can't move to Python 3, you'll have to make your own display routine if you don't like the default `repr()` display.  Something like:

```
D = {u'aka':[u'2019\u730e\u8840\u90fd\u5e02(\u6e2f)',u'\u9ece\u660e\u65f6\u5206']}

def dump(item):
    L = []
    if isinstance(item,dict):
        for k,v in item.items():
            L.append(dump(k) + ':')
            L.append(dump(v))
        return '{' + ', '.join(L) + '}'
    elif isinstance(item,list):
        for i in item:
            L.append(dump(i))
        return '[' + ', '.join(L) + ']'
    else:
        return "u'" + item + "'"

print dump(D)
```

Output:

```
{u'aka':, [u'2019猎血都市(港)', u'黎明时分']}
```

Note this is by no means complete as a generic dumping utility.

In Python 3 `repr()` has been updated:

```
>>> print(D)
{'aka': ['2019猎血都市(港)', '黎明时分']}
```

Answer (score -1):

Call `json.dump` or `json.dumps` with  `ensure_ascii=False` options, then you will get raw utf-8 encoded string.

referenced by https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

`json.dump(obj, fp, skipkeys=False, **ensure_ascii=True**, check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None, indent=None, separators=None, encoding="utf-8", default=None, sort_keys=False, **kw)`¶

you can try

`df['douban_info'][0].to_json(ensure_ascii=False)`

to get attribute values displayed with chinese character.

Comment: Do you mean that I should do this when I read data into pandas dataframe?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pandas. you can try code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406511/write-json-format-using-pandas-series-and-dataframe, i think that the options are same about pandas json functions.

Comment: This isn't the problem. That's not a json string, because it contains `u"` before the start of each string. The problem seems to be that repr does not leave Unicode chars in place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186073/change-ipython-notebook-json-file-encoding/27187050, I think this is a same question.

Comment: Not the same. In that question, the json actually contains the characters `\u...`. In this case, python is just inserting those as part of `repr`

Comment: This question is **How to output chinese**, the output is right for repr, but is not show in native character.

Comment: The problem here is that `to_json()` returns a unicode object, which once again has repr called on it, which converts the unicode chars to `\u`